# Swift libtinfo.so.5 no version information

Tags: linux, swift

Trying to install swift in archlinux, managed to make the REPL work by installing the swift-bin AUR. However, I cant build binaries as `swift build` returns me:

```
swift: /usr/lib/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by swift)
/usr/bin/swift-build: /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/swift/linux/libFoundation.so)
```

I already have `ncurses5-compat-libs` installed. What am I missing here?

Comment: You have a version mismatch somewhere, the AUR swift-bin package was updated 2017-04-08, so I would grab the current PKGBUILD (if you didn't already) That's all I can think of... Your question is probably more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: you can check this this http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54649/problems-making-the-swift-compiler-to-work

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  Trying to make it work with Swift4 on Arch now and running into this issue.

Comment: The problem is on swift bin... Install other aur.